# log4net class library is not outputting any log

Tags: logging, visual-studio-2015, log4net, .net-4.6

So I have several projects in a solution. 
I know you can create a log helper class to do this in the SAME project. However, I was wondering if I can extend this to all projects

I created a class library so that each of my project can get a log4net logger base on their project name.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Log4NetLogHelper
{
    public class LogHelper
    {
        public static log4net.ILog GetLogger([CallerFilePath]string filename = "")
        {
            return log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(filename);
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the filename inside the helper class and it was correct. However, there's no log output. (nothing is logged in the file and etc). I'm 99.99% sure it is not my config because the log4net works fine if I don't use the helper class.

```
using Log4NetLogHelper;

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch =true)]

namespace A
{
    public class B
    {
       private static readonly log4net.ILog log = LogHelper.GetLogger();
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          log.Error("test");
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. I think the problem was that I forgot to put the `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch =true)]` in my library project